# Upgrade Fedora 13 to Fedora 16

Tags: operating-systems, fedora-13, fedora-16

I had installed Fedora 13 in 50% of the hard disk size, in other half i installed Windows 7. Now i am unable to start Fedora and even cant upgrade Fedora 13 to Fedora 16.

It gives an message that you can not upgrade Fedora 13 to Fedora 16 directly, upgrade it to 14, 15 then 16. Even it don't allow to install a fresh copy of Fedora. Is there any way to install it.

Comment: If you don't need to upgrade, and are happy to start over, then boot from the F16 disk and do a fresh install that way.  It is not possible for the existing OS to prevent this.

Comment: Have you tried, you know... following the directions?

Comment: I am booting using USB. I cant see the partition that are already in my hard disk. The whole drive is shown as one. I need to keep my win 7 copy as it is. Is there any way out?